# Bootstrap Media Query not working at 576px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

My bottom Navbar styles simply aren't being applied at exactly 576px.
[image]

`CSS` I'm using for styling:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .bootomTab {
    display: flex !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }

  .bootomTab a {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

In my HTML I'm using bootstrap breakpoint `sm` whose dimension is ≥576px according to the bootstrap [official doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/):

```
<nav className="bootomTab d-none d-sm-flex col-sm-2 col-lg-3">
            <div className="logo">
              <a href="/home">
                <img src="/twitter.png" alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <a href="/home">
              <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/search">
              <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/notifications">
              <i className="fas fa-bell"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/messages">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/profile">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </a>
            <div className="mobileHide">
            <a href="/signout">
              <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
            </a>
            </div>
 </nav>
```

[Sample Code:](https://c8vvg.csb.app/)

**Edit**: After applying styles suggested by @amirify, third column is created at 576px.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML? I'm not sure I believe bootom - is that really it? Looking in your browser's devtools to see what CSS is actually being applied can help.

Comment: @AHaworth Edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule inside your `media query`.

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  nav {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
  .mainSectionContainers {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
 }
```

Comment: @YogeshYadav I did it inside codesandbox and it worked. are you sure you placed that inside media query?

Comment: can you share your forked sandbox. please.

Comment: inside style.css https://codesandbox.io/s/twitter-responsive-ui-forked-hpkbr?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: I tried it, works like charm! Thanks. I really appreciate it if you tell me how to remove the third column showing at 576px now.

Comment: @YogeshYadav Do you mean the notification (bell) Icon? I updated sandbox. check it out.

Comment: No. I have edited the question. you can check.

Comment: Nevermind I resolved it by  using `.mainSectionContainers {
    width: 100% !important;
  }` Thanks again :)